# sharing java beans between maven modules in an app server

Tags: java, maven, jboss, javabeans, maven-module

I'm not sure what I'm attempting is possible, therefore I'm looking for advice / guidance on the subject. Say I've got **2 maven modules** running simultaneously, with **module B** having **module A** specified as **dependency**. I've also got an **application server** running - WildFly (JBoss) - that is serving as a launching entity for those modules.

The problem: I need to access the same **bean instance** (object reference) on **module B** that is first initialized in **module A**. Basically, this is a type of *resource sharing* / *shared memory* access. Conventional ways that come to mind are **CRUD** operations on a **database**, but I'm wondering if there's an actual way of **sharing bean instances** between running modules? Could the **AS** help in this regard in any way as well - as in, perhaps I could move the initialization there and somehow share the instances between modules?

Thank you.

Comment: How are module A and B deployed in WildFly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that EJB is a possible solution to the requirement you are exposing.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Comment: what about Spring, can the same be achieved? If so - how?

Comment: Check this Spring documentation, it should tell you how http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html